# Calculating forces on a hexacopter which create yaw

Tags: unmanned-aerial-vehicle, yaw

I'm trying to design a mathematical model of a hexacopter, and while researching the mechanics of the object I could not figure out how to  calculate the total torque on the drone in 'Z' axis that creates yaw forces. I have found some equations that suggest the torque from one motor is equal to:

```
[angular velocity]^2 * [some constant] (one source called it the drag constant)
```

Can anyone explain to me the reasoning behind this equation and how should I approach measuring this constant, given that I have a specific motor to work with.

Answer (score 1):

There are various z-Moments acting on the a Drone. Some frome Accelerating the propellers and others from just rotating the propellers. The Moment you are searching is the result of the drag of the Propeller. This force is always acting in the other direction of the spin direction of the propeller. This Moment also used to control yaw (but isnt as effective as tilting the propulsion unit about some degrees to generate a higher moment expending the attainable moment set). You can find a database of these coefficients with formulas here: https://m-selig.ae.illinois.edu/props/propDB.html
(Maybe you can find your propeller here)

You are searching the Coefficient CQ, so:

M_z = rho * n^2 * D^5 * C_Q

where rho is the density, n the speed in rev/s and D the diameter in m.
To make it easier to understand and see the connection to the drag force I will rearrange the variables in the formula:

M_z = rho * (n*D)^2 * D^2 * C_Q * D

So, n*D can be interpreted as the velocity of the propeller. D^2 can be interpreted as the cross sections therefore resulting in

M_z = rho * V^2 * S * C_Q * D

comparing this to the drag Force:

D = rho * V^2 * S * C_D

We now can interpret the the Last D as a lever arm.
(But in reality this formula comes from de-dimensionizing the moment)

You can measure this Moment from the Output power of the Motor(P_motor_out = P_prop = 2 * pi * n * Q) or from the input power if you know the efficiency of the motor. The best way is to use a torque cell. You can also check, how the measurement were executed in the previously mentioned database.